# extra line on insertHtml in contentControl

Tags: ms-office, office-js, word-addins

in office API for Word 2016 I am using contentControl's insertHtml function to insert html-formatted text. The text inserts as a block element with an extra line added to the end. The similar functionality in API for Word 2013, setDataAsync with coercionType "html" worked correctly and inserted an inline element. Is there a way to specify that I need an inline element.

Basically what I need when I try to insert `(text <i>inserted</i> with <b>insertHtml</b>)` is:

> this is existing text (text *inserted* with **insertHtml**) followed by
>   more text

What I am getting is:

> this is existing text
>
> (text *inserted* with **insertHtml**)
>
> < blank line >
>
> followed by more text

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue on the Word JavaScript API and we are working on a fix for it. in the meantime please use the setSelectedDataAsync with coercionType HTML to achieve what you need.  insertHtml will have the same behavior.

here is some code samples to add some context of the question. basically the intend is to grab the current selection and insert some HTML. there are 2 ways of doing this in the API (see below). Right now the insertHtml is adding a paragraph mark at the end, which is a bug we'll fix soon.

```
function insertHtmlSample() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var mySelection = context.document.getSelection();
        mySelection.insertHtml("text <i>inserted</i> with <b>insertHtml</b>", "before");
        return  context.sync();

    }).catch(function (error) {
        app.showNotification(error.message);
    })
}


function InsertHtmlOld() {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("text <i>inserted</i> <p> with </p> <b>insert  <p>Html</b> </p> Hello!!!  ", { coercionType: 'html' });
}
```

Comment: thank you, that works perfectly. Just to elaborate, since I am inserting into a contentControl, I had to call contentControl.select() first.

Comment: yes, the alternative is that you create a binding to that content control (i am assuming you are creating the cc, right?)  you can use the [bindings.createFromNamedItemAsync ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123590.aspx) method for that (make sure when you create the content control to supply a title, which is whats used to ID the content control. then you can use the binding.setData method to write on the CC.